# Extract sum of coefficients in a binomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

I have two questions:

(1) Given $(1-x+x^2)^{3n}=c_0 + c_1 x + \dots +c_{6n} x^{6n}$, find $c_0+c_1+ \dots +c_n$.

I manage to find $c_0+c_1+ \dots +c_{6n}$ by putting $x=1$ but I do not know how to find the required sum up to $n$. To me, it seems that it omits terms from $n+1^{th}$ to $6n^{th}$ and thus I do not know how to find it properly.

(2) Futher given $(1+x)^{3n}=k_1 +k_1 x + \dots k_{3n} x^{3n}$, find $c_0 b_0 + c_1 b_1 +\dots c_{3n}b_{3n}$.

I have no idea on how this is related to question (1).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x=1/y$ in the first relation and multiply by $y^{6n}$ to get

$$(1-y+y^2)^{3n}=c_0y^{6n}+c_1y^{6n-1}+\cdots+c_{6n}$$

Set $x=y$ in the second to get $(1+y)^{3n}=k_0+k_1y+k_2y^2+\cdots+k_{3n}y^{3n}$

So, $\sum_{r=0}c_rk_r$ is the coefficient of $y^{6n}$ in

$$(1-y+y^2)^{3n}\cdot(1+y)^{3n}=\left[(1-y+y^2)(1+y)\right]^{3n}=(1+y^3)^{3n}$$

Now the $r$th term of $(1+y^3)^{3n}$ is $$\binom{3n}r(y^3)^r=\binom{3n}ry^{3r}$$

So, we need $3r=6n\iff r=?$

Comment: thanks, get the idea to the question (2). Do you have any ideas to question (1)?

Comment: @nam, Welcome! Are you sure that it is not $$c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{6n}?$$ What's the source of the question ?

Comment: indeed, I am not so sure about the indices because it is hand written by my teacher. However, the question is asked to do the sum in Question (2) by making use of the result of Q(1). So, it may even be $c_0 + c_1 + \dots +c_{3n}$. What do you think? (Sorry for posting an unclear question.)

Comment: @nam, Observe that $k_r=0$ for $3n+1\le r\le6n$  So, $$\sum_{r=1}^{6n}k_rc_r=\sum_{r=1}^{3n}k_rc_r=$$

Comment: I got the answer of Q(2) is $3nC2n$. Am I correct?

Comment: @nam, have you understood my post correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24251/discussion-between-nam-and-lab-bhattacharjee).